# How to generate table of content with OPmac macro \kuk without duplicities of pages?

Tags: table-of-contents, plain-tex, opmac

I'm trying to create a slideshow in TeX using Opmac. But when I use macros `\kuk` and `\maketoc`, there are duplicities in table of content.

Is any possibility to generate the line in the toc only for a new section? Or read the toc without duplicities..?

I need just get a list of sections and use it on a slide as a progress bar.

For example I have this code:

```
\input opmac
\chyph

\margins/1 a5l (1,1,1,1.2)cm        % page format
\input ctimes  \typosize[17/22]      % font

\def\pg{\vfil\break}                % new page
\begitems                           % start items

% slideshow with \kuk     
\let\kuk=\relax 
\def\kukdata{}
\long\def\kukstart#1\kuk{\addto\kukdata{#1}%
   \tmpnum=0 \def\endkukdata{}\expandafter\sumkuk \kukdata\sumkuk
   \kukdata\endkukdata \vfil\break \kukstart
}
\long\def\sumkuk#1{\ifx#1\sumkuk
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum>0 \addto\endkukdata{\enditems}\advance\tmpnum by-1 \repeat
   \else 
     \ifx#1\begitems \global\advance\tmpnum by1 \fi 
     \ifx#1\enditems \global\advance\tmpnum by-1 \fi
     \expandafter\sumkuk \fi
}
\count1=1  
\def\advancepageno{\ifx\kukdata\empty \global\advance\pageno by1 \global\count1=1
                   \else \global\advance\count1 by1 \fi}
\def\pg{\def\kukdata{}\vfil\break}

\kukstart                           % if \kukstart in comment, it prints document normal

\tit Slideshow in \TeX

\pg

\notoc\nonum\sec Table of content

\maketoc

\pg\kuk

\nonum\sec First section

\kuk
* First item
\kuk
* Second item
\kuk
* Third item

\pg\kuk

\nonum\sec Second section

\kuk
* First item 
\kuk
* Second item 
\kuk
* Third item

\enditems
\end
\kuk
```

This is the result (I have been using pdfcslplain):

[image: result]

But I need this:

[image: wanted result]

Please only plain TeX solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I redefine `\sec` to compare the argument to the previous one and write the note in the `.ref` file only if they differ.

Of course this will fail if you have two consecutive sections with the same title.

```
\input opmac
\chyph

\margins/1 a5l (1,1,1,1.2)cm        % page format
\input ctimes  \typosize[17/22]      % font

\def\pg{\vfil\break}                % new page
\begitems                           % start items

% slideshow with \kuk     
\let\kuk=\relax 
\def\kukdata{}
\long\def\kukstart#1\kuk{\addto\kukdata{#1}%
   \tmpnum=0 \def\endkukdata{}\expandafter\sumkuk \kukdata\sumkuk
   \kukdata\endkukdata \vfil\break \kukstart
}
\long\def\sumkuk#1{\ifx#1\sumkuk
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum>0 \addto\endkukdata{\enditems}\advance\tmpnum by-1 \repeat
   \else 
     \ifx#1\begitems \global\advance\tmpnum by1 \fi 
     \ifx#1\enditems \global\advance\tmpnum by-1 \fi
     \expandafter\sumkuk \fi
}
\count1=1  
\def\advancepageno{\ifx\kukdata\empty \global\advance\pageno by1 \global\count1=1
                   \else \global\advance\count1 by1 \fi}
\def\pg{\def\kukdata{}\vfil\break}

\def\sec#1\par{\ifnonum\else \global\advance\secnum by1 \fi
  \sechook {\globaldefs=1 \seccnum=0 \tnum=0 \fnum=0 \dnum=0}\relax
  \edef\thesecnum{\othe\chapnum.\the\secnum}\let\thetocnum=\thesecnum 
  \def\dotocnumafter{%
    \def\current{#1}%
    \ifx\current\old\else\wcontents\Xsec{#1}\gdef\old{#1}\fi}%
  \printsec{#1\unskip}\resetnonumnotoc
}



\kukstart                           % if \kukstart in comment, it prints document normal

\tit Slideshow in \TeX

\pg

\notoc\nonum\sec Table of content

\maketoc

\pg\kuk

\nonum\sec First section

\kuk
* First item
\kuk
* Second item
\kuk
* Third item

\pg\kuk

\nonum\sec Second section

\kuk
* First item 
\kuk
* Second item 
\kuk
* Third item

\enditems
\end
\kuk
```

[image]

I left `Table of content`, but beware it should be “contents”.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great solution. And of course it should be "contents", my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I would tackle the problem by making the behaviour of `\sec` variable: you only want to write to the TOC on the first use per page. That can be done a few ways, perhaps the easiest is with a switch. Just showing the code added to your example (before the first page):

```
\newif\iffirstslide

\def\sec#1\par{\ifnonum\else \global\advance\secnum by1 \fi
  \sechook {\globaldefs=1 \seccnum=0 \tnum=0 \fnum=0 \dnum=0}\relax
  \edef\thesecnum{\othe\chapnum.\the\secnum}\let\thetocnum=\thesecnum
  \iffirstslide
    \def\dotocnumafter{\wtotoc1\rm{#1}}%
  \else
    \def\dotocnumafter{}%
  \fi
  \firstslidefalse 
  \printsec{#1\unskip}\resetnonumnotoc
}

\def\pg{\def\kukdata{}\firstslidetrue\vfil\break}
```

Depending on the real use case, you might need one switch per section level, detection of the first slide per page or similar to cover subsections and so on.